# "bokeh: command not found" while connected via remote desktop (Windows Remote Desktop Connection)

Tags: bokeh, remote-access, xrdp

I'm using a Windows 10 machine to connect to a remote Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS machine via Windows' built-in Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) using xrdp 0.9.5.
The setup was working fine up until now.

However, I'm getting a weird error when trying to use bokeh through the Windows' remote desktop connection:

`bokeh: command not found`

Obviously, bokeh 1.4.0* is installed, but none of the bokeh commands work. I always get the same error message from above. I also can't pip install bokeh as it says bokeh is already installed. On the remote Ubuntu machine, the bokeh commands get recognized fine when running them directly on the Ubuntu machine (no remote connection).

Did anyone face similar problems or knows a possible solution?

*I can't really upgrade to the newest bokeh version because I unfortunately need to stick with Python 2.7 ...